# Why does ы have a soft sign in it?

Tags: буквы

It's the only letter with two disconnected parts. How did this letter ы come about?

Comment: Sorry, you're wrong way about "the only letter with two disconnected parts". What about `Й`, so called "shortened `И`"? And wait, there is `Ё`, as "`Е` with 2 dots".

Comment: @YurySchkatula Those can be considered diacritics. Something very different and common across orthographies of many languages.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The letter ы is a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) of [ъ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AA) and [і](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_I_(Cyrillic)).

In the past, these were both separate vowels (pronounced something like /ɤ̞/ and /i/) and ы was considered as a sort of combination of those two vowels.

Comment: Modern (and even pre-1918) 'ъ' is very much disconnected from its roots. This link can provide some insight: ['Yer'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yer).